# change selected value of drop down list C# .Net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am trying to change the value of a drop down list from a database, in the database it can either be a tinyint value of 1 or 0. currently when I run my code it removes everything from the drop down list and replaces it with the value from the database, which wont give the user an option. Preferably im trying to get it when the value is 1 in the database "Active" appears in the users drop down but they also have the option to select "Retired" value 0.
Below is my code,

ASPX

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDriverActive" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Active</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Retired</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Below is the C# code

```
ddlDriverActive.SelectedValue = reader.GetString(Convert.ToString("DriverActive"));
```

Value 0 = Retired
Value 1 = ACtive

i am trying to get it when the driver active row is = 1 then active is selected, but the user can change to retired Value = 0 then update the sql query at a later date.

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem. Seem very straight forward to me.

Comment: Dropdownlist has two items "Active" "Retired" and you select the value from a database value what is wrong?

Comment: When i get the data from the database it overrides the values i manually set rather than selecting one of them. e.g. i have active or retired. when i get the tinyint 1 it changes the text of the Drop down list to True removing the values set in the html. EDIT : when i select the data from the database it removes my pre defined values with the one i inserted.

Comment: `DriverActive` is tinyint, right? You need to check the value and then set selected value. `if(reader.GetString(Convert.ToString("DriverActive"))){  ddlDriverActive.SelectedValue = "Active"} else {  ddlDriverActive.SelectedValue = "Retired"}`